# Getting a certain value out of a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json file with two arrays, one of them is nested. I need to get the numbers from the nested array and match them with a value (id) in the unnested array so that I can send the matched values in the unnested array to another function. I have been trying to figure this out for two straight days and haven't been able to figure out what it is I am doing wrong. Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

I have the data to my json here for reference.

```
{
  "videos": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Lego!",
      "created": 1509804047011,
      "duration": 5,
      "poster": "./videos/small.png",
      "video": "./videos/small.mp4"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Big Bunny",
      "created": 1507804047011,
      "duration": 62,
      "poster": "./videos/bunny.png",
      "video": "./videos/bunny.mp4"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Prufu myndband",
      "created": 1505904047011,
      "duration": 3600,
      "poster": "./videos/16-9.png",
      "video": "./videos/bunny.mp4"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Prufu myndband með löngum texta sem fer í tvær línur",
      "created": 1504904047011,
      "duration": 220,
      "poster": "./videos/16-9.png",
      "video": "./videos/bunny.mp4"
    }
  ],

  "categories": [
    {
      "title": "New videos",
      "videos": [1, 2]
    },
    {
      "title": "Amazing videos",
      "videos": [1, 3, 4]
    },
    {
      "title": "Funny videos",
      "videos": [2, 3, 4]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the categories and find the videos:

```
for(const {title, videos} of data.categories){
  for(const id of videos){
    const video = data.videos.find(v => v.id === id);
    //do whatever with video
  }
}
```

Alternatively if you just want to get the videos that are mentioned in the nested categories:

```
const ids = new Set( data.categories.reduce((res, videos) => res.concat(videos)) );

const result = data.videos.filter(v => ids.has(v.id));
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, will see how it turns out :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `map` over the videos array like this:

```
const videoIds = data.videos.map(video => video.id);
console.log(videoIds)
```

This will return an array containing all `id`s in the videos array.

Comment: Thanks I will try and use this, I will give you a feedback how it works out.